# org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException

Tags: spring

error occurs in runtime. 
please explain

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spring configuration for the triangle bean is wrong.

The class name of triangle is `com.aish.java.Triangle`

The filename for triangle is `Triangle.java`

correct bean config:

```
<bean id="triangle" class="com.aish.java.Triangle"/>
```